# Forms12c Frm-42431 Unable to Initialize Debugger Debugger Error

Tags: oracle, weblogic, weblogic12c, oracleforms

Version Information
Weblogic 12.2.1.3, 
Forms [64 Bit] Version 12.2.1.3.0

I have installed Forms Builder only on my machine. I follow the proper configuration steps to configure the forms.
Full installation of WebLogic on a separate server.

When I am trying to run a module through the form developer's debug push button it shows the below message

"Frm-42431 Unable to Initialize Debugger"

I made the change in formsweb.cfg allow_debug=true, and also debugger.jar is included in class path in default.env.

Help is also not working. When I try to open the help system. The below message is open.
FRM-18105: Failed to start the help system.

Please help me find out the solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your local environment variable(FORMS_BUILDER_CLASSPATH) is the same as what is in the registry editor(check under KEY_OracleHome1). If not the same or you don't find it in the local environment variables just do this:

Open Registry Editor -> computer -> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINES -> Software -> Oracle -> KEY_OracleHome1

Look for FORMS_BUILDER_CLASSPATH right-click -> modify -> Copy all under value data
Paste it into the notepad and look for ORACLE HOME under FORMS_BUILDER_CLASSPATH do the same copy all under value data textbox that the path of your files.

Then go back to your note pad replace all '%ORACLE_HOME%' with the path you copied on oracle home.

It should look like this after replacing all :

```
C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\jlib\frmbld.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\jlib\importer.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\jlib\debugger.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\jlib\utj.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\jlib\ewt3.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\oracle.bali.share\share.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\jlib\dfc.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\oracle.help\ohj.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\oracle.help\help-share.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\oracle.help\oracle_ice.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\oracle.bali.jewt\jewt4.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\forms\java\frmwebutil.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\forms\java\frmall.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\forms\java\frmwebsocketjsi.jar
```

Then go to environments variable under system variable click new then variable name add FORMS_BUILDER_CLASSPATH on value add all text you copied on note pad after replace.

Close and Open forms again it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

If working on Windows then simply do the following
(Assuming your ORACLE_HOME directory is D:\Oracle12C)

1. Right Click on My Computer and then Click on Properties
2. Click on Advanced system settings
3. Go Advanced tab and then click on Environment Variables button
4. Under system variables, Click on New button
5. Enter Variable name as FORMS_BUILDER_CLASSPATH
6. Enter Variable value as below (remember to replace ORACLE_HOME which in my case is D:\Oracle12C)

   `D:\Oracle12C\jlib\frmbld.jar;D:\Oracle12C\jlib\importer.jar;D:\Oracle12C\jlib\debugger.jar;D:\Oracle12C\jlib\utj.jar;D:\Oracle12C\jlib\ewt3.jar;D:\Oracle12C\jlib\share.jar;D:\Oracle12C\jlib\dfc.jar;D:\Oracle12C\jlib\ohj.jar;D:\Oracle12C\jlib\help-share.jar;D:\Oracle12C\jlib\oracle_ice.jar;D:\Oracle12C\jlib\jewt4.jar;D:\Oracle12C\forms\java\frmwebutil.jar;D:\Oracle12C\forms\java\frmall.jar`
7. Click on OK button and then Restart the Form builder. Happy coding :)